# Reproducing the log4shell on windows machine

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

I am trying to reproduce the log4shell issue with the following code. (I am doing this for learning purposes) but somehow it is now property working. Here is the controller class with logger.

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String index(@RequestHeader("X-Api-Version") String apiVersion) {
    logger.info("Received a request for API version " + apiVersion);
    return "Hello, world!";
  }
}
```

When I hit the API, logs get printed and also some logs the on [JNDI-Injection-exploit](https://github.com/welk1n/JNDI-Injection-Exploit) console. It is not creating the `test.txt` file which I am expecting. The command does create a file when I execute it on the cmd console.

[image]

Comment: "I am doing this for learning purposes" - What exactly are you trying learn here? I'm not sure helping with attempts to use current critical vulnerabilities would be in line with SO's policies (at least it wouldn't be in line with mine).

Comment: IMHO your code shows that your service (HomeController) is vulnerable to log4shell because just by logging the `X-Api-Version` header it can be tricked into accessing the JNDIExploit-LDAP-Server. That the LDAP server itself doesn't execute the passed in command is due to the (assumed) robustness of the LDAP server, but that has nothing to do with log4shell (which affects your `HomeController`)